# Допустимо ли писать обращение от имени компании во множественном числе? Пример: Компания Альфа готовы взяться за реализацию проекта

Tags: согласование, деловой-язык, обращение

Допустимо ли писать обращение от имени компании во множественном числе? 
Пример: Компания "Альфа" готовы взяться за реализацию проекта.

Comment: Нет. Это противоречит русской грамматике. (см. ответ Alex_ander). Но вопрос даже не в этом. *Зачем* так писать?! Что вы хотите подчеркнуть этим множественным числом?!

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это недопустимо. Указанное в явном виде *видовое наименование* "компания" при отсутствии прочих ориентиров должно согласовываться по числу со сказуемым. Порассуждать о возможности рассогласования названия "Альфа" с множественным числом сказуемого можно было бы напр. в случае *объединённых верфей* "Альфа", если бы опущенное наименование (верфи) было известно читателю. Но возможен такой вариант (представители компании обозначены во множественном числе):

> **Мы**, компания "Альфа", **готовы** взяться за реализацию проекта.